# How to change keyboard language dynamic in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, keyboard

Here is my question:

First Screen would choose Language Option like English/Hindi/Punjabi/Spanish
2nd screen would have 3 text inputs and when user starts typing then a keyboard based on the selected language from screen 1 should appear.

Is is possible to achieve this?

Comment: I think you should too create a custom keyboard for this case because the keyboard language depends on OS settings.

Comment: Yes, but how to create custom keyboard?

Comment: You don't want to create a custom keyboard.  First off, a good keyboard is a lot of work-  entire companies do that.  Second, you'll piss people off when the features they expect in their keyboard don't exist.  You can try to do this by overriding the locale (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900023/change-app-language-programmatically-in-android).  But you should rethink this feature-  you'll be fighting Android every step of the way, because it really doesn't want to be used like this.  And if you did write a custom keyboard, ReactNative wouldn't work.  You'd need to go full native.

Comment: You are able to redefine de locals but is not suggested I think. There is a lot of ways to create a custom keyboard and you can customize the keyboard view what is depending on your language settings, but it is too complicated, try something easier.